# Simpe UDP optimisation

Tags: java, android, sockets, udp, audio-streaming

I am making a music streaming application in which I need to transfer data over UDP.
Currently I am sending packets of size 1.4 kilobytes every 10ms. But this seems to be slow. Now I have read that packet size of 1400 is advised because of MTU issues. Also packet pacing should be done to reduce loss of packets. 
I tested over 3g, and the loss in quality is not that much. Perhaps i can increase my packet size, or reduce the pacing ? 
Can someone suggest an optimum strategy ?
Also I would appreciate any other suggestions regarding UDP streaming.
Thanks

The sender :

```
while(audio_stream.read(buf, 0, BUF_SIZE) != -1) {

                final DatagramPacket pack = new DatagramPacket(buf, BUF_SIZE,
                        InetAddress.getByName(connection.getRecIp().substring(1)),
                        Integer.parseInt(connection.getRecPort()));
                datagramSocket.send(pack);
                bytes_count += BUF_SIZE;
                Log.d("Ayush", "bytes_count : " + bytes_count);
                Thread.sleep(70L, 0);
            }
```

The receiver :

```
while(receivedBytes < length) {

                final DatagramPacket pack = new DatagramPacket(new byte[BUF_SIZE], BUF_SIZE);
                try {
                    datagramSocket.receive(pack);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return false;
                }
                if(pack.getLength() < BUF_SIZE/2) continue;
                mappedByteBuffer.put(pack.getData());
                receivedBytes += pack.getLength();
//Some more code for other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Currently I am sending packets of size 1.4 kilobytes every 10ms.

Are you sending audio or video.  If you use 320 Kbit/s MPEG you need 40 KB/second or 400 bytes every 10 ms.  128 Kbut/sec would require 160 bytes per 10 ms.

> But this seems to be slow.

Why?

> Now I have read that packet size of 1400 is advised because of MTU issues.

The MTU is closer to 1500 and this applies to TCP not UDP.

> Perhaps i can increase my packet size, or reduce the pacing ?

The larger the packet, the more you lose when one goes missing.  I would try 0.5 KB packets as these have been a good size for me in the past.

Comment: I am streaming mp3 music. The streaming was very slow. Ill try 0.5KB. And sorry my pacing was actully 70ms. Ill try reducing this too.

Comment: OK so if you are streaming 512 bytes at a rate of 128 Kbit or 16 kByte you need to send 32 per second, or every 31 ms.

Comment: Hi, I could use one more advice. Since I do not have means of properly testing this, could you give your opinion on more thing :
I am experiencing around 7% packet loss. I was thinking if I create say, x sockets and stream the file in parts, i.e., stream length/x part of the file on each socket, will it help reduce the packet loss ?

P.S using smaller packet and reducing the pacing to 10 did improve the stream quality, I think packet size is more important than pacing

Comment: @Dexter The packet loss is likely to vary on a range of factors including the network between the server and the device itself.  You may find you need to adapt what you do based on the client. i.e. you should get feedback from the device as to what the miss rate is.  You might have to send each packet twice, say half a second apart to ensure you get almost every packet at least once.

Comment: Ok, I get it, there is no silver bullet. Ill dig into QUIC and perhaps keep TCP as a fallback in highly noisy networks.
Thanks for your help.